# How to use grep command to list dot based names

Tags: regex, grep

I am trying to grep some of the services but it does not print exactly what I am looking for.

One thing I see in the grep strings is that the names are having  dot `.` jointed names.

I am trying below but not getting the desired output.

```
# systemctl list-unit-files | egrep -w "autofs.service|sssd.service"
autofs.service                                disabled
sssd-autofs.service                           indirect
sssd.service                                  disabled
```

or

```
# systemctl list-unit-files | egrep "autofs|sssd[.service]"
autofs.service                                disabled
sssd-autofs.service                           indirect
sssd.service                                  disabled
sssd-autofs.socket                            disabled
```

Expected Output:

```
# systemctl list-unit-files | egrep -w "autofs.service|sssd.service"
autofs.service                                disabled
sssd.service                                  disabled
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```sh
grep -E '^(sssd|autofs)\.service'
```

Here,

- `^` - start of string
- `(sssd|autofs)` - a group matching either of the two substrings
- `\.service` - a `.service` substring.

See an [online demo](https://ideone.com/0lqjhA).

Answer (score 1):

Use `grep` with `-P` option for Perl regexes, parentheses to group the patterns, and (optionally in your case) `\.` or `[.]` to match a literal period, rather than special character `.`, which matches any character:

```
grep -P "(autofs[.]service|sssd[.]service)"
```